# Check-out failed ? What this error actually means?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

Some time while **saving data** from admin panel in joomla, error message occurs which says **check-out failed**. What this error **means** ? When will this error **occurs** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you mention means that another user is editing the item (usually article or module), or has left the item without closing properly (usually by clicking the <kbd>Back</kbd> button in the browser, or simply closing the browser window without clicking <kbd>Save</kbd>, <kbd>Save & Close</kbd> or <kbd>Close</kbd>).

The complete error message is:

> Error Check-out failed with the following error: The user checking out
>   does not match the user who checked out the item.
>
> You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page
>   (#196).

*#196 is replaced with the ID of the item.*

If you take a look at the article manager, you might see a padlock before the title of some of your articles:

[image: Joomla article manager padlock]

This means the article is *locked* to the user displayed in the tooltip. If you are a superuser, (and are sure no-one is editing the article at the moment) you can force access to the article by clicking the padlock, or by selecting one or more articles and clicking <kbd>Check-In</kbd> in the toolbar.

If there are many padlocks, you can find "Global Check-In" in the "System" menu:

[image: Global Check-In]

Here you'll be able to Check-In (remove the padlock) for all items with one click.

For more details, take a look at [this answer by @FFrewin](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5214/check-out-failed-with-the-following-error-the-user-checking-out-does-not-match).